# Strange Results with DiscretizeGraphics

Tags: graphics3d, 3d-printing

Using some code from http://www.bugman123.com/Hyperbolic/index.html

```
n = 7; m = 3; dt = 2 Pi/n; dtm = 2 Pi/m; r = 
 1.0/(1 - Sin[dt/2]/Cos[dtm/2]); R = r Cos[(dt + dtm)/2]/Cos[dtm/2];
ToMatrix[z_, 
   r_] := (I/r) {{z, r^2 - z Conjugate[z]}, {1, -Conjugate[z]}};
alist = Table[
  ToMatrix[r Exp[I t], r - 1], {t, dt/2, 2 Pi, dt}]; Tlist = 
 Join[{IdentityMatrix[2]}, alist];
homography[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}, z_] := (a z + b)/(c z + d);
FindT[T0_, Tlist_] := 
  MemberQ[Tlist, 
   T_ /; Abs[homography[T, 0] - homography[T0, 0]] < 1.0*^-3];
i2 = 1; Do[i1 = i2 + 1; i2 = Length[Tlist]; 
 Do[Scan[(T = Tlist[[i]].#; 
     If[! FindT[T, Tlist], Tlist = Append[Tlist, T]]) &, alist], {i, 
   i1, i2}], {2}];
plot = Show[
  Graphics[Map[
    Line[Table[
       z = homography[#, R Exp[I t]]; {Re[z], Im[z]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 
        dt}]] &, Tlist], AspectRatio -> Automatic]]

plotFilled = Show[Graphics[
 Map[{RGBColor[RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]], 
  Polygon[Table[
    z = homography[#, R Exp[I t]]; {Re[z], Im[z]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 
     dt}]]} &, Tlist], AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

to make Poincaré hyperbolic tilings

[image: Poincaré hyperbolic tiling]
[image: Poincaré hyperbolic tiling]

and some code I grab from here

```
Options[Extrude] = 
  Join[Options[Graphics3D], {Closed -> True, Capped -> True}];
Extrude[curve_, {zmin_, zmax_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{info, points, color, tube, caps}, info = Flatten[{curve}]; 
   points = Select[info, Head[#1] === Line &][[1, 1]]; 
   If[OptionValue[Closed], points = Join[points, {points[[1]]}]]; 
   color = Select[info, Head[#1] === Directive &]; 
   If[Length[color] == 0, color = Orange, 
    color = First[Select[color[[1]], ColorQ]]]; 
   tube = Polygon[
     Partition[
      Flatten[Transpose[(points /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y, #1} &) /@ {zmin,
           zmax}], 1], 3, 1]]; 
   If[OptionValue[Closed] && OptionValue[Capped], 
    caps = (Polygon[points /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y, #1}] &) /@ {zmin, 
       zmax}; tube = Flatten[{tube, caps}], tube = {tube}]; 
   Graphics3D[(Flatten[{color, #1}] &) /@ tube, 
    FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics3D]]]];
```

I wanted to make some pretty 3D printed drink coasters:

```
plotSheet = 
 Show[Extrude[#, {-0.01, 0.01}, Capped -> True, Boxed -> False] & /@ 
   plot[[1]]]
plotTube = 
 Graphics3D[{JoinForm["Miter"], 
   plot[[1, 2 ;; -1]] /. 
    Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[Append[#, 0] & /@ pts, 0.05, rest]}, 
  Axes -> True]
plotFilledSheet = Show[plotSheet, plotTube, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Fancy drink coaster]

However, when I try to discretize this to make it a filled region, I get

```
DiscretizeGraphics[plotFilledSheet]
```

[image: Bad discretization]

I have also tried simply exporting as an STL but then the tubes around the outer heptagons in the STL are not connected.  CAD software then treats it as an open region (surface) and trying to close it lead to awful results.

Saving as an OBJ gave results just like DiscretizeGraphics.

Does anyone have thoughts on how I can get this and the bowl I want to make printed?

[image: Bowl]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sigh*. Indeed, that is really frustrating. Tubes are always a pain to work with and junctions are particularly hard to get pretty.

The following is a brute-force method that represents the final `BoundaryMeshRegion`s as sublevel sets of (i) the distance function to edges of the heptagons and (ii) the surface to of the heptagons.  In the end, I "join" the `BoundaryMeshRegion`s with `Show` and by exporting to STL. It seems to work but I cannot check if your external program excepts the resulting STL file as input. I also tried `RegionUnion` on `S1` and `S2`, but that took forever...

```
data = Map[ Table[z = homography[#, R Exp[I t]]; {Re[z], Im[z], 0.}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, dt}] &, Tlist];
L = MeshRegion[
   Join @@ Most /@ data,
   Line[Join @@ (Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@Partition[Range[7 Length[data]], 7])]];
P = MeshRegion[
   Join @@ Most /@ data,
   Polygon[Partition[Range[7 Length[data]], 7]]
   ];
f = RegionDistance[L];
g = RegionDistance[P];
θ1 = 0.05;
θ2 = 0.01;
z =.

R1 = ImplicitRegion[f[{x, y, z}] <= θ1, {{x, -4, 4}, {y, -4,4}, {z, -θ1 1.1, θ1 1.1}}];
R2 = ImplicitRegion[g[{x, y, z}] <= θ2, {{x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -θ1 1.1, θ1 1.1}}];

S1 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[R1, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
S2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[R2, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First

Export["a.stl", Show[S1, S2]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 24.8892
>
> 6.34708
>
> 79.5849

You may control the resolution of the generated `BoundaryMeshRegion`s by setting the option `MaxCellMeasure` as desired.

Comment: That works wonderfully...  thank you!  Now I just gotta get my 3D printer fixed.

Comment: I am glad to hear that (that it worked, not that your printer is broken ;)  ). You're welcome!

Comment: This might be a topic for a new question but I'll ask here.  Is there a way to change/override Norm in the RegionDistance function to something besides Euclidean?  Obviously I'm thinking of different cross-sections.

Comment: Hm. None that I know of. I also think that it would be hard to design more interesting cross sections by specifying a distance function. What you have in mind would probably depend on the directions of the edges of the heptatgons. This would be so aniotropic that it probably cannot be represented by a norm...

Comment: My original thought was just a square cross-section.  But, then I started thinking "crazy".  Something like DistanceFunction for Nearest.